# What does the "::" mean in C++?

Tags: c++, scope-resolution-operator

What does this symbol mean?

```
AirlineTicket::AirlineTicket()
```

Comment: @Paul R: Exactly. Here's the book list: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: @PaulR  Not everyone who arrives upon this question is looking to learn C++. I, for example, just happened to be skimming some C++ code  and wanted to get the general idea of what the program is doing and needed a quick reference :)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

:: is the [scope resolution operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_resolution_operator) - used to qualify names. In this case it is used to separate the class `AirlineTicket` from the constructor `AirlineTicket()`, forming the qualified name `AirlineTicket::AirlineTicket()`

You use this whenever you need to be explicit with regards to what you're referring to. Some samples:

```
namespace foo {
  class bar;
}
class bar;
using namespace foo;
```

Now you *have* to use the scope resolution operator to refer to a specific bar.

`::foo::bar` is a fully qualified name.

`::bar` is another fully qualified name. (`::` first means "global namespace")

```
struct Base {
    void foo();
};
struct Derived : Base {
    void foo();
    void bar() {
       Derived::foo();
       Base::foo();
    }
};
```

This uses scope resolution to select specific versions of foo.

Answer (score 16):

In C++ the `::` is called the [Scope Resolution Operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_resolution_operator).  It makes it clear to which namespace or class a symbol belongs.

Answer (score 3):

It declares a namespace. So in AirlineTicket:: you can call all public functions of the AirlineTicket class and AirlineTicket() is the function in that namespace (in this case the constructor).

Answer (score 0):

AirlineTicket is like a namespace for your class.  You have to use it in the implementation of the constructor.