# Why are begin(container) and end(container) accessible everywhere but aren't in global namespace?

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator

I can do

```
std::vector<int> v;
begin(v);
```

yet, when I do

```
std::vector<int> v;
::begin(v);
```

I get

> `error: ‘::begin’ has not been declared ::begin(v);`

It works again if I put

```
using namespace std;
```

at the top of the file, which I find weird, because I thought doing `::begin` would actively prevent it from using `std::begin`. What is happening here?

Comment: Read about: Argument dependent lookup: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl put simply the namespace of any arguments is searched when trying to find the function.

Comment: These functions are part of the `std` namespace, so why would you expect `::begin()` or `::end()` to work?

Comment: @user0042 Because `begin(container)` works without `using namespace std;`

Comment: I don't wonder about the error in 2nd sample. I wonder that the 1st works (without `using namespace std;`). I'm afraid I will never fully understand how names are resolved in C++... (That's why I'm using it carefully.)

Comment: Ah, I now know. It was a duplicate. @Scheff look at the question linked.

Comment: "Argument dependent lookup" would've been my guess - but nothing which I _know_ or even would dare to explain to anybody... I believe I stick to "using carefully"...

Comment: This question could really use an answer which references the posting about Argument-Dependent Lookup (ADL). There are really two things going on here. The first is that ADL used by the compiler allows for the first use of `begin(v)` as the compiler matches up `std::vector<int>v` with the `begin()`. However the second use of `::begin(v)` changes what the compiler is doing since the use of `::` prevents the ADL search by the compiler. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5345527/what-does-the-mean-in-c

Comment: @RichardChambers But it magically works again after `using namespace std`, though

Comment: @kim366 `using namespace std` brings all the names in the `std` namespace into the global namespace.  So the global namespace qualifier will now find them. This why `using namespace std` is such a bad thing to do.

Comment: @RichardCritten Ah, I understand